# Do we have separate end points for metadata information (server generated data) in Rest API

Tags: rest

Normally it is said that you should have the same model for your GET and POST request of some resource in Rest.

There is some server generated data getting generated for that resource, Do we need to return it in the GET request or Do we need to have a separate end point for getting meta data information.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's fine and to be expected to have some server generated data in certain scenarios, like CreatedDate, for example. It's still the same resource, it will be `POST`-ed without that property (or null, or populated but ignored anyway on the server), but it should certainly be filled in the `GET` request.